# CSS selector for text only

Tags: css

I'm capturing images for tutorials for a site that uses company names that are rather confidential, so must blur the texts. With this HTML

```
<div class="draggable ad">
  <div propid="8584" class="___2_4x4">COMPANY NAME inside DIV</div>
</div>
```

blurring the lot is of course easy:

```
.draggable.ad div {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

But DIV inside "draggable" has a background image that must not be blurred:

```
.___2_4x4 {
  background: url(/images/ad.png);
}
```

Is it possible to select (and blur) only the text, not the DIV itself? This is obviously not the way to go:

```
.draggable.ad div:text {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Sure, it's possible to wrap the text in a span and blur the span etc, but as I need it only temporarily for tutorial images, it'd be nice to not have to change the code. Is this possible?

Comment: How is blurring confidential data ever a good way? Anybody can simple check the source and see your confidential data.

Comment: It's a good way if I make a screenshot of it for the tutorial. No way to unblur the JPG :)

Comment: If all you care about is taking a screenshot, then why do you bother with blurring? Take your screenshot and then edit the jpg to remove (or blur) any confidential data. It's much easier to edit a jpg than manipulate the DOM and background images.

Comment: Well, if you have plenty of time to mess about in Photoshop then sure, that's the way to go

Comment: I wasn't too specific in the original task, as this was not relevant: magazine layout with 100 pages, every one of them having background thumbnail of the layout (needs not to be blurred) and the name of the advertiser on top of it (needs to be blurred). Must have screenshot of it. Cannot be done in 5 seconds in Photoshop or Paint, sorry. Modifying the CSS can be done in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This style blurs the text only:

```css
div {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
}
```

```html
<div>
  Confidential Data
</div>
```

Comment: How is that hiding the confidential data? I don't even need to view the source, I can simple select the text and the hidden confidential data will be highlighted and easy to read.

Comment: @RacilHilan This doesn't really hide anything, only blurs it. This is also what the OP's example does

Comment: As I said in the question, I need to capture the IMAGE of the blurred-texted site.
This is a perfect solution for my immediate problem, nice thinking! It does not answer my actual question though: is there a "text selector" in CSS. If not then this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `filter` you could add add dummy text in a psedoelement and apply filter that way. To hide the original text you can use `font-size: 0` - which has the additional advantage of the text being unselectable.

Obviously, anyone can still look at the source code and see the original text.

```css
.___2_4x4 {
   background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature) no-repeat;
   height: 200px;
   font-size: 0px;
}

.___2_4x4:after {
  content: 'fake company name';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable ad">
  <div propid="8584" class="___2_4x4">COMPANY NAME inside DIV</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution as well. Using 'filter' is not necessary, in that sense GalAbra's answer is more 'correct'. As I understand, there's no 'text' selector in CSS as such?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `opacity` property on the `div` and that will affect both the content (text) and background (image). The value is between 0 (completely transparent) and 1 (completely opaque):

```css
.___2_4x4 {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.draggable.ad div {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable ad">
  <div propid="8584" class="___2_4x4">COMPANY NAME inside DIV</div>
</div>
```

To address the content (text) and background (image) separately, you can use `color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0);` for the content (or `transparent` like suggested in the other answer) and `background: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0);` for the background. Make sure this CSS for the background comes after the original CSS than shows the image. The idea is that you want to override the original background with a new one:

```css
.___2_4x4 {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.draggable.ad div {
  color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.___2_4x4 {
  background: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable ad">
  <div propid="8584" class="___2_4x4">COMPANY NAME inside DIV</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the thing, I need to address the background and contents(text) separately..

Comment: Why, do you have other content that you don't want to hide? See my updated answer for addressing them separately.